# Getting Arabic text from .txt file?

Tags: android, arabic

Hey,
I have Arabic text in a txt file that I would like to show in a simple EditText,
Though when I do that here is what I get:
http://i55.tinypic.com/66g09z.png

Here is the code I use to get the text from the .txt file:

```
    txt1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01); 

    try{

           File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/1.txt");
           FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);          
           BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));           
           String readString = new String();             

           //just reading each line
           while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){          
               txt1.setText(txt1.getText().toString()+readString);                
           }             
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e){

           e.printStackTrace();          
        }

}
```

How can I get proper Arabic letters into the EditText?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of android do you run? Android has no support for Arabic locales up until 2.3 version. You can find more info about locales supported on corresponding SDK pages. For example, list of SDK 2.3 supported locales is [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/sdk/android-2.3.html#locs).

Comment: @Konstantin Burov This is the Android emulator, its running 2.1.. is it possible to access the System files in the emulator to add the Arabic font?

Comment: @Omar why don't just use 2.3 or newer then?

Comment: @Omar: Fonts won't be enough; the system has to be smart enough to recognize that Arabic is written right-to-left, and in 2.1 it probably won't know that and will write the Arabic "backwards".  (And will probably use the presentation form of each letter.)

Comment: @Omar 2.3 Supports only Egypt and Israel locales. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Konstantin Burov I debugged the app in my phone (which displays and has Arabic), and I still have those  "?" signs as they are in the picture.. So I guess this isnt related to wether the phone has or not the Arabic font.. Is there something special to do in order to get proper Arabic?

Comment: I tried with a different .txt and it worked and showed the letters normally, but if i create a .txt with a notepad and try to read it in the app, it displays question marks.. 
Working: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18331007/working.txt 
not working: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18331007/notworking.txt

is there any difference?

Comment: @Omar the working one contains UTF-8 content, the other one uses non-UTF encoding. What stops you from making a file using first method?

Comment: @Konstantin Burov that solved the problem.. i never paid attention on which encoding it was. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that a font with Arabic characters is installed, and set the font of the EditText to it.  The former is the annoying part.  (I think I made SwiftKey do it for me by telling it to download the appropriate language modules.)

Comment: geekosaur      This is the Android Emulator.. How can I install Arabic font to it?